# android's graphical layout

Tags: android, layout

seems like the Android ADT's new graphical layout has changed, but it's a pain to add/drop stuff, especially because I do not have control over the layout on the outline where I can drop something inside a linearlayout for example. Does anyone know if it's possible to come back to the old graphical layout?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try [ADT 9.0.0 Preview-3](http://tools.android.com/download).